# Как вызвать в конструкторе обобщенного класса, унаследованного от обычного, конструктор для обобщенного поля с параметром?

Tags: c#, generics, конструктор

Имеется обычный класс в своем пространстве имен

```
namespace Common
{
    class CommonObject
    {
        protected int size;

        protected CommonObject(int size)
        {
            this.size = size;
        }
    }
}
```

с конструктором, требующим обязательного параметра `int size`.
У него есть наследники. Обычные:

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class CalculatorObject : Common.CommonObject
    {
        protected CalculatorObject(int size) : base(size) { }

        protected virtual void Calculate() { }

    }
}

namespace SuperCalculator
{
    class SuperCalculatorObject : Calculator.CalculatorObject
    {
        protected SuperCalculatorObject(int size) : base(size) { }

        protected override void Calculate() { }
    }
}
```

И обобщенный:

```
namespace Solver
{
    class SolverObject<Calc> : Common.CommonObject where Calc : Calculator.CalculatorObject 
    {
        Calc calculator;

        protected SolverObject(int size) : base(size)
        {
            calculator = new Calc(size);
        }

        protected void Solve()
        {
            calculator.Calculate;
        }

    }
}
```

И ошибка кроется в `calc = new Calc (size);` - `Не удается создать экземпляр переменной типа "Calc", так как у нее отсутствуют ограничения new().`
Проблема в том, что конструктор обязательно должен быть с параметром `size`.

Я понимаю, можно обойтись и без обобщений, просто создав класс `SolverObject : Common.CommonObject` и дополнительно передать в конструктор экземпляр класса `CalculatorObject`, но тогда придется его отдельно создавать...

Хотелось бы при создании

```
SolverObject<SuperCalculatorObject> = new SolverObject<SuperCalculatorObject>(size);
```

сразу привязывать одно к другому...

Может это всё как-то проще или совсем просто решается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8).

```cs
namespace Solver
{
    class SolverObject<T> : Common.CommonObject where T : Calculator.CalculatorObject 
    {
        T calculator;

        protected SolverObject(int size) : base(size)
        {
            calculator = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), size);
        }

        protected void Solve()
        {
            calculator.Calculate;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's alive!!! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xos2MnVxe-c

Comment: Спасибо огроменное - я уж думал всплакнуть слегка... ))) Какая-же дотнет штука бездонная... o_O

Comment: Набор только иметь ввиду что такого конструктора может не быть. Лучше использовать фабрики

Comment: @serg.tortilliani галочка слева от ответа. :)

Comment: Да я треугольничек прокликал, а про галку забыл - помню, что нажать что-то нужно, а про главное - забыл )))

Comment: Мне вот очень интересно, как по описанию
"Activator.CreateInstance
Создает экземпляр указанного типа, используя конструктор, который наиболее полно соответствует указанным параметрам."
можно найти, что данная проблема решается именно так - да я даже не представляю как можно до такого додуматься... "соответствует указанным параметрам"... Ну да )))

Comment: @Андрей NOP Тут вся суть в том, что я все такие объекты строю так, что они наследуются от общего перво-предка, у которого он есть - и он единственный... protected CommonObject(int size)... Ведь если есть конструктор с параметрами - он же заменяет стандартный конструктор и не даёт возможности его вызвать... Ведь так?

Comment: @serg.tortilliani когда конструктор приуствтует, стандартного конструктора нет. Если ни один констрктор не объявлен, используется стандартный. Так что можно ответить, что да, так.

Comment: @aepot Ну я просто Троелсена всё осиливаю... Начал с 4.6 - пока читал, вышел 4.7 )))

Comment: @aepot Только сейчас понял, что ответ звучит как - используй Силу, Люк! )))))